# Which Shaivite sect believes God is the operator of the Universe but not the source?

Tags: philosophy, yoga, vedanta, brahma-sutras, shaivism

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3797/36), by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school, which bases its tenets on the doctrines laid out in the Brahma Sutras, a work by the sage Vyasa that summarizes and systematizes the philosophical teachings of the Upanishads. You can read the Brahma Sutras [here](http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm).

In any case, in Adhyaya 2 Pada 2 of the Brahma Sutras, Vyasa refutes various rival schools to Vedanta.  In particular, he says [this](http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm):

> Topic-7: God Is Not a Mere Superintendent
>
> 37. For the Lord there can be no creatorship, for that leads to incongruity.
> 38. And (the incongruity arises) because of the impossibility of a relationship.
> 39. And (the position is untenable) because of the impossibility of (Nature) coming under (His) direction. (Or) And (God cannot be
>       proved), since no physical support (adhisthana) is possible for Him.
> 40. Should it be argued that God will direct Nature like (a man directing) the organs, then it cannot be so, for that will result in
>       God’s having experiences (of happiness, sorrow etc.). (Or) If a body,
>       equipped with sense-organs, be assumed for God, (we say that) this is
>       not possible; because of (consequent) experiences etc.
> 41. God will be subject to finitude or loss of omniscience.

Now most commentaries on the Brahma Sutras, including Adi Shankaracharya's Brahma Sutra Bhashya [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34213.htm) and Ramanujacharya's Sri Bhashya [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48239.htm), interpret these Sutras as (in part) a refutation of the views expressed in the Shaiva Agamas, aka the Shaiva Tantras.  But I found one commentary, the Srikantha Bhashya which you can read [here](https://archive.org/details/TheVedantaSutrasWithSriKanthaBhashya), which has a very different perspective on things.

The Srikantha Bhashya was composed by Srikantha Sivacharya, a member of the Shaiva Siddhanta sect.  Shaiva Siddhanta is a Shaivite sect based on the Shaiva Agamas and the poetry of the 63 Nayatanars, just as Sri Vaishnavism is based on the Pancharatra Agamas and the poetry of the 12 Alwars.  So naturally you'd expect Srikantha to object to the notion that the Brahma Sutras are trying to refute Shaiva Siddhanta.  Srikantha offers two potential alternative explanations for who Vyasa is criticizing:

1. In [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfX9A.jpg) from the Srikantha Bhashya, Srikantha says this:

   > The Tantrikas, the so-called orthodox, those who profess to follow the Parameshwara Agamas, without knowing the real import of their teaching, hold that Pati, the Parameshwara, is the mere efficient cause, though, according to Shruti, he is both the material and the efficient cause of the universe.
2. In [this later excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXEUB.jpg) from the Srikantha Bhashya, Srikantha says this:

   > Wherefore we maintain that this adhikarana refers to the Yoga-Smriti of Hiranyagarbha which speaks of Ishwara as the mere efficient cause.  Therefore the adhikarana is properly intended to overthrow the Hiranyagarbhagama.

My question is about the two belief systems that Srikantha discusses.  First of all, who are those "so-called orthodox" followers of Shaiva Agamas who believe that Ishwara is not the material cause of the Universe?  Is this a reference to the Lakukisha's sect of Pashupata Shaivism, or Abhinava Gupta's sect of Kashmir Shaivism, or some rival sub-sect of Shaiva Siddhanta?

Second of all, is it true that the Yoga school, which was founded by Brahma or Hiranyagarbha as described in the Mahabharata, believes that Ishwara is the efficient cause of the Universe?  It certainly believes that he's not the material cause, since it posits Pradhana/Prakriti as the material cause?  But I'm not aware of any statement in the Yoga Sutras that says Ishwara is the efficient cause.  I've just seen statements like the notion that he's the first teacher of Yoga, the notion of worshipping Ishwara, and the notion that he dwells within everyone.

For those who aren't acquainted with this philosophical terminology, the material cause of something refers to what it's made of, and the efficient cause of something is what causes it to happen.  So "Brahman is the material cause of the Universe" means that everything is made of Brahman, and "Brahman is the efficient cause of the Universe" means that everything that happens is directed by Brahman.

Comment: are there any commentaries of commentaries?

Comment: @Sai Sorry, what are you asking?  Are you asking whether there are any commentaries on the Srikantha Bhashya?  Yes, the Shaivite philosopher Appaya Dikshitar wrote commentaries on it.

Comment: yeah that's what I was asking. Because that would be a good place to look for your q.

Comment: @Sai Well, unfortunately I don't have an English translation of Appaya Dikshitar's Sivarka Mani Deepika, which is his commentary on the Brahma Sutras based on the Srikantha Bhashya.  I only have an English translation of the Shivadvaita Nirnaya, which is a work by Appaya Dikshitar which tries to reinterpret the Srikantha Bhashya in order to argue that Srikantha's philosophy of Shivadvaita is actually nothing but pure Advaita.  (Appaya Dikshitar was an Advaitin.). The latter work doesn't systematically discuss every Sutra.

Comment: @Sai In any case, I think it's possible to find an answer to my question without using commentaries on Srikantha's work.  I just need to find out whether there are any Shaivite sects which believe that Shiva is the efficient cause of the Universe but not the material cause.   And similarly whether the Yoga school believes that Ishwara is the efficient cause of the Universe.

Comment: @Sai By the way, I just posted another question about Shaiva Siddhanta: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8897/36

Comment: @Keshav -   Dr.S.M.S. Chari has brought out a book  named "Indian Philosophical System based on Paramata bhanga of Swami desikan. The author seems to say , that Srikantha's SiVa Advaita considers Siva as nimitta karana, unlike the pure vedanta school of thoughts like Advaita and Visistadvaita.

Comment: @Keshav - Abhinava gupta's Kasmira Siva Advaita, is based purely on Kashmira saiva agamas . So, It  also considers the supreme as nimitta karana only. So, i think, Srikantha might be referring to both the schools, as both are based on Pasupata sect and saiva agama schools or only to Pasupata sect, as it is considered as the oldest saivaite sect.

Comment: @Keshav - In a critical study of Srikanthabhasya as commented by Appaya dikshita, it is shown that the the work is dubious nature written by some shavaite called Nilakanta, Even, Vallabhacharya has remarked that Srikantha is Ramanuja matha cora (a thief who copied the work of Ramanuja)

Comment: @Keshav "The author seems to say , that Srikantha's SiVa Advaita considers Siva as nimitta karana, unlike the pure vedanta school of thoughts like Advaita and Visistadvaita." Are you saying that Srikantha believed that Shiva is the nimitta katana (efficient cause) but not the upadana karana (material cause)?  That makes no sense because in his commentaries on these sutras he is defending the Shaiva Agamas by saying that when correctly interpreted, they don't really say that Shiva is only the efficient cause.

Comment: @Krishna Wasn't Abhinavagupta a pure Advaitin?  So wouldn't be have beliefs similar to Adi Shankaracharya, regarding Brahman being the material cause as well?  And yeah, Nilakantha is another name for Srikantha Shivacharya, and his commentary and philosophy have a lot in common with Ramanunacharya's Visishtadvaita, except Vishnu is replaced by Shiva.  By the way, most scholars think that Appaya Dikshitar distorted the meaning of Srikantha's commentary to make seem Advaitic when it actually was more in line with Visishtadvaita.  In his work, Srikantha explicitly criticizes Abheda-Vada.

Comment: @Keshav - Abhinavagupta might be an advaitin, but his work,  Kashmira SIVAADVAITA, is said to be more based on Kashmira saiva agamas, unlike the traditional vedantanta schools which are primarily based on upanishads and brahmasutras. You are right that are evidences to suggest that Appaya dikshita distorted Srikantha bhasya to suit Advaita.

Comment: @Keshav - Infact, Appaya Dikshita himself is considered more as a saiva, than a advaitin. Infact, many say that the present day modern advaita  philosophy is distorted and more aligned with teachings of Appaya dikshita , than the ancient Shankara or his immediate followers. This distortion of advaita seems to have started from Vidyaranya time and seems have become strong during Appaya dikshita time, which is evident from his works trying to prove Parvati pati Siva as Supreme deity and the same time playing the game of "Everyone is same.."

Comment: @Krishna Well, there's the issue of which god you consider supreme, and then there's the issue of the relationship between Jivatma and Paramatma.  Srikantha and Appaya Dikshitar were certainly both Shaivites, but in regard to the relationship between Jivatma and Paramatma, Appaya Dikshitar was an Advaitin while Srikantha was more to the Visishtadvaita side.  By the way, has Abhinavagupta or any other Kashmir Shaivite written a commentary on the Brahma Sutras?

Comment: @Keshav - Srikantha copied Visistadvaita, but still it is defective is what i heard, because, he considers Supreme (here SIVA) as instrumental cause only and Siva - sakti is Material cause. One might contend that both are same, but there is a difference and against the vedanta sutras, which considers the Supreme Brahman as both materail and instrumental cause. The Kasmira SiVAAdvaita is considered as the philosophy of Abhinava gupta, though he basis it more on Kashmira Saiva agamas and even doesnt accept the the brahman of Upanishads as Supreme reality.

Comment: @Keshav - The author S.M.S. Chari says that for Abhinava gupta the universe is projection Siva shakti and is not illusory manifestation of Supreme being due to maya as in the case Shankara's Kevala advaita.

Comment: @Krishna  I think Srikantha does believe Brahman is both the efficient cause and the material cause.  That's why he says "The Tantrikas, the so-called orthodox, those who profess to follow the Parameshwara Agamas, without knowing the real import of their teaching, hold that Pati, the Parameshwara, is the mere efficient cause, though, according to Shruti, he is both the material and the efficient cause of the universe."  He's saying that the only reason that other followers of Shaiva Agamas believe that the supreme lord is not the material cause is that they're misinterpreting the Agamas.

Comment: @Krishna  And in this excerpt he explicitly says this: http://i.imgur.com/ExeKEvI.jpg "Anyhow, our conclusion is that Ishvara is not a mere efficient cause."

Comment: I think you might have known but in case you don't. Kashmiri Shaivism believes in Shiva being every cause - including material and efficient. But personally, I don't have criteria to eliminate truth/philosophy based on the various causes.

Comment: It is not Lakulisha since he too believed Shiva as both the efficient and material cause of the universe. However, it seems the Pasupata system before Lakulisha believed that Brahman is only the efficient cause. See this: https://www.hinduismtoday.com/modules/smartsection/item.php?itemid=3246

Answer (score 3):

According Siddha Tirumular, a saint who has written Tirumantram, important text of Shiva Siddhanta, Maya is material cause, the Lord is efficient cause and His cit/sakti is the instrumental cause.

Comment: Yo, Shaiva Siddhanta says...But it is a comment. Can you cite something or add something to it to make this answer look like an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Creation is first of the Five acts.

Tirumandiram 401: Maya Sakti Born of Bindu Performs the Five Acts. 

From Bindu by Orderly triangle denoted 
The honeyed Sakti Tripurai devoluted; 

She it is the Compassionate Sadasiva became; 

She it is the five merciful deeds performs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. There are 10 Shiva Agamas which support the above view, of Shiva only being the efficient cause. The 18 Rudrabheda Agamas are non dualistic cum dualistic. The Veerashaiva sect again follows a Philosophy similar to the Vedantic Vishistadvaita. The Kashmiri Shaiva school bases themselves on the 64 Bhairava Agamas which are Non dualistic, believing Shiva to the cause of literally everything. Also, if you notice, whenever an Agama is being revealed to someone Lord Shiva loves dearly with his heart, such as Maa Parvati, Lord Skanda or Lord Vishnu, the Agamas are generally non dualistic.
Consider a few verses from the Sarvajnanottara Agama revealed to Lord Skanda by Lord Shiva

> "This Lord Shiva who shines forth within the heart of all beings, who is self luminous, who represents himself as all the souls, worlds, worldly objects, who creates and directs all the tattvas, who is of the nature of all tattvas evolved by him from maya, who is inconceivable, who exists in the highest transcendental plane which is beyond the range of all other planes occupied by the  and trancends all tattvas from Shiva tattva to prithvi tattva is verily beyond the reach of speech, mind and name"
>
> Sarvajnanottara Agama Vidya Pada 2.4-5

Similar things have been said in the Devikalottara Agama. In fact, the Ajita Agama, one of the foremost of the Agamas among the list of 28 Agamas of South Indian Shaivism (10 Shivabheda and 18 Rudrabheda), has the following verses regarding this.

> "The Lord(Shiva) is all that. There is nothing different from Him. He is the material cause,the mahat and the ahamkara, the tanmatras...... "
>
> Ajita Agama 2.13-17

Also, notice, this Agama was again revealed to Lord Shiva's beloved Lord Vishnu. Indeed Vishnu is regarded as the foremost devotee of Lord Shiva in Shaivism.

The abover verse itself proves Lord Shiva is the material cause. The Shaiva Siddhanta of dualism primarily started from the Meykandar Shaastras. It is also true that Agamas like Paushkara, Mirgendra and Matanga do not accept Shiva as material cause. So the philosophy of the Shaiva Agamas is not easy. No one can just put one point label on it with superficial understanding

Comment: Can u pls share ajita agamas and sarvajnottara agama Vidya para english translation pdf ?