# What are some Shaivacharyas's commentry on Brahmasutras? What does it Proclaim?

Tags: shaivism, commentary

I am wondering that if Just as Vaishnavacharyas have written various commentaries on Brahmasutras, or Shaivacharyas also have also written their own commentaries on Brahmasutras, Vedas, Gita and proclaiming Paramshiva to be the supreme brahman declared in Vedas.

What are that commentaries and what does it proclaim in general?

Comment: You can read Srikantha’s commentary here https://archive.org/details/TheVedantaSutrasWithSriKanthaBhashya/mode/2up. It is called Siddhant Deepika

Comment: Also related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8872/which-shaivite-sect-believes-god-is-the-operator-of-the-universe-but-not-the-sou

Comment: Yes its related, thanks for linking it. this question can be one of the answers to the question but I am also looking for more claims.