# Commentary on Kena Upanishad besides Shankara's?

Tags: upanishads, kena-upanishad

Which commentaries of the Kena Upanishad exist?

Besides Shankara's well-known commentary, are there other commentaries which are recommendable?

**EDIT:** I did not find the answer to my specific question in the [link](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3794/2995).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whose commentaries on the Vedas and Upanishads are most followed?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/whose-commentaries-on-the-vedas-and-upanishads-are-most-followed)

Comment: I do not think so, that question is way too generic. This is highly specific.

Comment: I personally like the commentary by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar, very insightful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides Shree Shankara [Shree Madhvacharyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhvacharya) commentary on Kena-upanishad  in english is available for PDF download .

---

Here is Shree Madhvacharyas Bhashya on [**Kena Upanishad**](http://www.nageshsonde.com/images/Bhashya_on_Kena_Upanishad.pdf) - Translated by Nagesh D. Sonde.

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more in addition to Sri Sankara's Bhashyam, which by the way exists in two versions.And there are tikas following the commentaries of the poorva-acharayas like Sri Sankara.

I don't have all the links because I suppose many of the old works are only available in prints (and I am still old fashioned). But I managed to get some links for the following ones.

First of all, [here is the link to Sri Sankara Bhashyam(s) for Kenopanisad](https://Sri%20Gambhirananda%27s%20translation%20-%20Advaita%20Ashrama%20edition%20https://archive.org/details/eight-upanishads-with-the-commentary-of-s-swami-gambhirananda)

[This one appears to be Anandagiri's Tika](https://archive.org/details/KenaUpanishadWithShankaraBhasyaAndAnandagiriTika/mode/2up)

[This one](https://archive.org/details/ken-upanishad-with-anandagiri-tika_202304/mode/2up) also is (supposedly) Sri Anandagiri's Tika. I didn't check if the title matched the content though. I assume it is possible for many Internet uploads to have titles mismatched with content. Also it appears like a Hindi translation.

Upanisad Brahmayogi wrote commentaries for all the 108 upanisads which includes dAsOpanisads. [Here is the collection, and the link specifically positioned on volume 1 of dAsOpanisad](https://archive.org/details/108_Upanishads_with_Sanskrit_Commentary_of_Upanishad_Brahma_Yogin/Dasonapanishads%20with%20Upanishadbrahman%27s%20commentary%20Vol%201/), in which you can find the commentary for kEnOpanisad.

[Here is a publication with both Sri Madvacharya's bhashyam (page 32) along with Sri Raghavendra Swami's Tika](https://archive.org/details/ishavasyatalavakarakathakaupanishadsaccordingtosrimadhvacharyabhashya1985/mode/2up)