# What is the difference between Cit in the word Sat- Cit- Ananda and Purusha?

Tags: consciousness, purusha

Cit = Consciousness and Purusha = Consciousness. Purusha is also known as Spirit . FIRSTLY can this Spirit be seen ? Secondly are Samskaras the veil that separate consciousness from super consciousness, and THIRDLY if this Spirit is seen is Ananda realized?

Comment: Chitta or Consciousness is one Swarupa of Atman/Brahman (Purusha or spirit) as preached by the Mahavakya `Prajnanam Brahman` from Aetareya Upanishad of Rigveda. Regarding other questions... can it be seen? Ananda realized? ok I'll write an answer to your couple of questions asked in the body...

Comment: *THIRDLY if this Spirit is seen is Ananda realized?* Yes, you can see the Lord (Purusha) who is the Supreme spirit, and then you can get moksha and eternal ananda (eternal happiness) as per the Svetasvatara Upanishad 6.12 says: "The wise who perceive Him (the one God, the one ruler of many) within their self, **to them belongs eternal happiness**, not to others." as I explained at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22356/2790 But if you happen to be an Advaitin then you'll not be interested in ananda because they just want to realize themselves as Brahman, they are not interested in ananda.

Comment: @brahma jijnasa, At the extreme corner of mans sight where consciousness and subconsciousness meet, where the phenomenal meets the noumenal, where the outer meets the inner stands there the Spirit Archer. If he is seen the arrow has already hit its target and the man becomes one in Spirit and Ananda.

Comment: @Frank I'm not sure did you get that analogy thing about archer and arrow that hits the target from the Mundaka Upanishad verse I quoted there. We as a jivatma are an archer and we (jivatma) are the arrow as well, and by the application of Om or the name of Lord Vishnu which serves as a bow we hit the target, ie Brahman.

Comment: @brahma jijnasa ya !  We realize Brahman when the Spirit Arrow has hit its target. The union is Bliss and all is God.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>The title and body are asking different questions, I'm answering three questions asked in the body of question. Btw, regarding Chitta or consciousness, it is one Swarupa of Brahman as preached by Mahavakya **Prajnanam Brahman** of Aitareya Upanishad of Rigvea.</sup>

> **Q.** FIRSTLY can this Spirit be seen ?

No, seeing is the function of eye which is one of the Jnanendriya (senses) and Brahman is beyond the all the senses as described in Kena Upanishad. In other words, eye is made from Pancha Mahabhuta and hence it can only see the physical things made up of Pancha Mahabhuta Whereas [Atman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21038/277) (the self) is beyond [3 Sharira](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24714/277) and [5 Koshas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3073/277).

> I-2. Because He is the ear of the ear, the mind of the mind, the speech of speech, the vital air of the vital air, and **the eye of the eye**, the wise, freeing themselves (from the identity with the senses) and renouncing the world, become immortal.
>
> I-3. **The eye does not reach there**, nor speech, nor mind, nor do we know (Its mature). Therefore we don't know how to impart instruction (about It). Distinct indeed is That from the known and distinct from the unknown. Thus have we heard from the ancients who expounded It to us.
>
> I-6. **That which man does not see with the eye, that by which man sees the activities of the eye**, know That alone to be Brahman, and not this (non-Brahman) which is being worshiped.

Though one can see the Sukshma Sharira and Karana Sharira through eyes as explained by Swami Vishwananda in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6787/277). So, talking about Atman, it can not be seen but can be *realized*.

> **Q.** Secondly are Samskaras the veil that separate consciousness from super consciousness

Well, Samskara is the total sum of impressions (of thoughts generated during experience of life) stored in the memory or mind as explained by Swami Vivekananda in his [work on Jnana Yoga](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_2/jnana-yoga/the_real_and_the_apparent_man.htm)

> What are the Samskaras? This mind is like a lake, and every thought is like a wave upon that lake. Just as in the lake waves rise and then fall down and disappear, so these **thought-waves** are continually rising in the **mind-stuff** and then disappearing, but they do not disappear for ever. They become finer and finer, but they are all there, ready to start up at another time when called upon to do so. Memory is simply calling back into waveform some of those thoughts which have gone into that finer state of existence. Thus, everything that we have thought, every action that we have done, is **lodged in the mind**; it is all there in fine form, and when a man dies, the sum total of these **impressions is in the mind**, which again works upon a little fine material as a medium. The soul, clothed, as it were, with these impressions and the fine body, passes out, and the destiny of the soul is guided by the resultant of all the different forces represented by the different impressions.

Since it is often said mind is alone the cause for man's bondage and liberation (4th Prapathaka of [Maitrayini Upanishad](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-sama-veda/maitrayani-upanishad/)), these Samskara affects one's level of spirituality but actually the thing that hides the true self is the Avarana and Vikshepa Shakti of Maya (refer Vivekachudamani 111, 113, 343, 344) i.e that separate individual consciousness from supreme consciousness in your words in question.

> **Q.** THIRDLY if this Spirit is seen is Ananda realized?

Yes, who realize the Atman, attains the supreme bliss of Brahman as described in  Brahm**ananda** Valli of [Taittiriya Upanishad](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-krishna-yajur-veda/taittiriya-upanishad/):

> यतो वाचो निवर्तन्ते । अप्राप्य मनसा सह ।
>   **आनन्दं ब्रह्मणो** विद्वान् ।
>   न बिभेति कुतश्चनेति ।
>   एतꣳह वाव न तपति ।
>   किमहꣳसाधु नाकरवम् । किमहं पापमकरवमिति ।
>   स य एवं विद्वानेते आत्मान स्पृणुते ।
>   उभे ह्येवैष एते आत्मान स्पृणुते । य एवं वेद ।
>   इत्युपनिषत् ॥ १॥
>
> II-ix-1: **The enlightened man** is not afraid of anything after **realising that Bliss of Brahman**, failing to reach which, words turn back along with the mind.
>   Him, indeed, this remorse does not afflict: "Why did I not perform good deeds, and why did I perform bad deeds? He who is thus enlightened strengthens the Self with which these two are identical; for it is he, indeed, who knows thus, that can strengthen the Self which these two really are. This is the secret teaching.

Comment: ya sorry about the messy questions. anyway, if the Ajna chakra has been opened and siddhis attained has one the ability to not only see the Spirit but also become one with it ? This has happened to m PS  should I edit the question ?

Comment: @FrankHestermann I recommend to read Yoga Sutras of Patanjali and Raja Yoga by Swami Vivekananda.