# Concept of Brahman according to different commentators of the Brahma-Sutra

Tags: brahman, brahma-sutras

Sri Adi Sankaracharya and the Acharyas of four major Vaishnava sects have written commentaries on Brahma-Sutra. How is the concept of Brahman different in each commentary from the other? A am asking only for brief answers. Not just the definition of different philosophies as discussed in the forum previously.

Comment: I think this is not duplicate as no as [that Q and A](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4064) does not analyse the concept of Brahman clearly

Comment: Related: [Dvaita vs Advaita vs Vishistadvaita vs Shuddhadvaita vs any other](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4064)

Comment: see the Introduction to this translation of the Brahma Sutras. It details out all the various concepts by the various commentators. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras