# Is there only one soul that is incarnated again and again at different times?

Tags: scripture, atma

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6fcK_fRYaI), there is only one soul in the universe which is incarnated at different times. Do scriptures agree with this theory?

Edit:
If Link Dies here is the story
[image]

Comment: No, an individual soul is different from collective Supersoul/God. Source of all beings is same, if you hide the heads of every human on earth, you can find only common structure of human with 206 bones,that commonality is projection of Supersoul. But driver of that common structure whether human or animal body in ego are infinite individual beings or animals or insects with their different Karmas and fates. Saying you are Hitler or Jesus because of non-duality overnight book study is stupidity of several neo-Vedantic foreign scholars and misinterpretation of Advaita.

Comment: The video is a little “western oriented”. They say anything and everything without knowledge. You might want to have a look at [this answer about different Vedantic philosophies](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14779/20129)