# How did Lord Shiv came to the world

Tags: shiva

I want to know that how did Lord Shiv, Lord Brahma & Lord Vishnu came to the world, before them, what was present ?

Comment: The Trimurti is birthless and deathless. They did not come to the world because they existed before the world, exist now, and will continue to exist after the world ends. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6833/119 Here is some information specific to Lord Shiva, but it applies to all members of the Trimurti. All the best.