# Dwaita and adwaita: What do they mean?

Tags: philosophy

What are the significant points that can be captured from the teachings of Sri Shankaracharya and Sri Madvacharya.

Are these concepts purely philosophical or are they religious?

If they are religious, what are they derived from?

Comment: See also this answer: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/4056/119

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by 'are the philosophical or are they religious'? Thanks

Comment: When I say religious I mean to say if it is pertaining to a god like Vishnu or Shiva and stories related to them. When I say philosophical I mean to say that the idea preaches one about how to lead ones life or how to think about life.

Comment: Well its actually both. Advaita is the philosophy of one-ness. Whereas Dvaita is philosophy of uniqueness. However Dvaita is also about worshipping and adoring Lord Vishnu (for Vaishnavites) and Lord Shiva (for Shaivites). Advaita is also about how all religious practices ultimately lead to union with the True Self or God. As you said in your other question. It is more about doing than simply reading. Therefore both these philosophies have various practical tools which they prescribe to attain that realization which they deal with. All the best.