# Are ego and attachment evil qualities as per Vedas?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, indriyas

I would like to understand more about ego and attachment from the perspective of Hindu Shastras and Vedas. Are these evil qualities?

If yes, how to get rid of these things from my mind?

Comment: Not evil per se but the two elements of maya that prevent one from attaining moksha. How to get rid of it - by yoga sadhana.

Comment: Ego and attachment are two of the six enemies of human beings. Ego manifests itself into ignorance & attachment leads to lust and when lust is not full filled it manifests into anger. Both ignorance and anger destroys `buddhi`. And when `buddhi` is destroyed, a human being is rendered incapable of knowing the truth about the purpose of life. Such soul remains entangled into material world and sensual pleasures. How to get rid of these things? Read this - [How do I control and slay indriyas senses](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-do-i-control-and-slay-indriyas-senses)