# I live in North America - how can I live a pious life?

Tags: practice, bhakti

Please, reveal to me the scriptures that can teach me to live in the way most holy, no matter where we live on earth. What practises shall I undertake. I love life and God, but I know my actions are not as pure as I need them to be.

How can I learn to become the best form of human I can be.

Comment: Please refer [How do I control and slay indriyas (senses)?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8828/3500)

Comment: you need to rephrase your question as personal questions are not allowed on this site. to answer your question, pray to God and find your Guru. If you pray to God sincerely your Guru will find you.

Comment: This book is an answer to your questions, it's a translation and elaborate commentary on the Bhagavad gita by one Vaishnava acarya (teacher), and gives a practical advices and answers on your questions: https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg You can read it online or you can order it in a book form from the publisher.

Answer (score 1):

It pleases me knowing that you want your life to be taken to the right track. In Hinduism, it can be a bit confusing to choose a deity who you want to fully follow but start by learning about Hinduism by reading the Bhagavad Gita which is the main Holy scripture in Hinduism by Shri Krishna. This first step is sure to guide your life in the right direction. Do meditation while chanting the name of your preferred deity (as all are same, just different incarnations) in your mind and thinking about nothing else except Him. When you develop a love for your Guru as we like to call our Ista Deva, you start to fear Him... not in the sense that he will punish you but in the sense that he will be disappointed in you. Just like when you have a crush on someone, you never want them to be angry or disappointed in you. So I would say when you choose your deity (you can choose the one which you feel most resembles to you), read more about Him and his teachings. Read His famous stories as this are the best way to develop love for Him. Try to act upon his teachings. Make a schedule for everyday which includes meditation in the name of your Ista Deva and puja or the chanting of religious hymns. Also do bhakti which means singing prayers and hymns in the name of God. Divine bhakti is divine Shakti (sacred and divine power). Bhakti is also a very enjoyable act. Find the nearest temple of your Ista Deva.

I hope I helped you to get some idea on what to do. And remember, when I say there are different deities I DO NOT mean that there are "Gods" in Hinduism. There is only one God, the Creator of everything, the All powerful, the Universal truth which is "Paramatma". But us humans are not able to worship him directly which is why we need a human form of his to worship. And that human form is none other that Almighty God himself on this mother Earth.