# Why do Sannyasis avoid looking at women?

Tags: women, sanyasi, yogi, indriyas

I have seen many Sannyasis (especially [Swaminarayan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaminarayan_Sampraday#Ascetics)) that don't look at women unless it's by accident. What is the cause behind this aversive behavior?

Comment: Do you mean "Sadhu's" or "Sanyasi's" ? Because Sadhu is more general term and can be used to denote a good person also.Sadhus generally give discourses and pravachanas to mass public , so in that case it's not applicable rule not to look at women.Some "Hatayogi" sadhus might be doing that as a special vow.

Comment: Thankyou. I have edited my post as I did not know the correct term to describe these individuals.

Comment: 'Not looking at women', seems to be a tradition of recent times. In modern times, the "lust" is more prevalent. May be due to that, many *SanyAsi*-s decide, not to get into contact of such subjects at all. Important part is 'Not to get affected by looking at women'. Just not looking at subject is merely a physical activity. What if, one doesn't look at women but constantly thinks about women? One & the same, isn't it. See this related answer: [How do the scriptures describe an ideal Sanyasi?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11178/1049)

Comment: @iammilind "What if, one doesn't look at women but constantly thinks about women?" A sannyasi avoids both looking at women as well as thinking about them..Both are contrary to celibacy.From my answer "...and this should be observed by VISION, THOUGHT or deed is called Brahmacharya or celibacy;

Comment: @Rickross, your answer is voted high & accepted, but IMO the interpretation of *Brahmacharya* is wrong. "Celibacy = state of abstaining from marriage and sex". While "*Brahmacharya* = *BrahM* (true self) + *charya* (practice) = practising true self". Krishna and VyAsa, both were said to be equal *BrahmachAri* as *Bhishma*. But both of them had sex. Krishna had multiple wives/kids & VyAsa had *niyoga* with 3 women. Same is true for RAmakrishna Paramhamsa. In short, relating any physical activities with *Brahmacharya* is ignorance. Unfortunately many books translate that way; so not your fault.

Comment: Its not sexist, Its the wrong word to use here. Its aversion to prevent subtle impressions of desire. @Utsav

Comment: @Utsav https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17797/why-do-sanyasa-scriptures-degrade-women?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For sannyāsis, not looking at women is only the starting point, it is not the destination. They are actually trying to [slay their indriyas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8828/2995) to the point that they are unaffected by the opposite sex.

Śaṅkarācārya says in [Vivekachūdāmani](http://www.realization.org/down/sankara.vivekachudamani.chaitanya.pdf):

> The deer, the elephant, the moth, the fish and the honey-bee---these five meet death because of their bondage to one of the five senses. **What then is the condition of a person who is attached to *all five*?**
>
> Sense-objects are even more virulent in their tragic effects than a king cobra. Poison is fatal to one who swallows it, but the sense-objects kill him who merely looks at them. with his eyes.
>
> **One who is liberated from the terrible bonds of desires for sense-objects, so very difficult to renounce, is alone fit for liberation and none else, even if well-versed in all the six schools of philosophy.**

In the [legend of Viśvāmitra](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga63/bala_63_frame.htm) from Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, we see how Viśvāmitra is temporarily distracted by the apsara Menaka and loses track of his *tapasya*.

In the [story of Dharma-vyādha](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03205.htm) we see that the sage, Kauśika, has probably mastered his senses over the opposite sex (as he has a lengthy conversation with the lady of the house) but he has not slayed his ego (*ahankāra*) and anger yet as he considers himself superior to a householder.

In the following [story of two monks](http://www.kindspring.org/story/view.php?sid=63753) (probably of Buddhist origin), we see how the younger one holds on to the thought of a woman even after the senior monk has long forgotten about the incident.

> A senior monk and a junior monk were traveling together. At one point,
> they came to a river with a strong current. As the monks were
> preparing to cross the river, they saw a very young and beautiful
> woman also attempting to cross. The young woman asked if they could
> help her cross to the other side.
>
> The two monks glanced at one another because they had taken vows not
> to touch a woman.
>
> Then, without a word, the older monk picked up the woman, carried her
> across the river, placed her gently on the other side, and carried on
> his journey.
>
> The younger monk couldn’t believe what had just happened. After
> rejoining his companion, he was speechless, and an hour passed without
> a word between them.
>
> Two more hours passed, then three, finally the younger monk could
> contain himself any longer, and blurted out “As monks, we are not
> permitted a woman, how could you then carry that woman on your
> shoulders?”
>
> The older monk looked at him and replied, “**Brother, I set her down on
> the other side of the river, why are you still carrying her?**”

So for a sannyāsi, it is not just about 'not seeing' or 'not touching' a person of opposite sex, the ultimate goal is to reach the state where you remain unaffected even when facing the opposite sex.

Comment: A very excellent answer and explanation  with perfect story. Definitely a fine answer that deserve upvote.

Answer (score 8):

The reason is actually very simple.For a Sanyasi or a Yogi maintaining celibacy(Brahmacharya) is one among the most important tasks.Its part of their sanyasa related vows as well.

So, they avoid all kinds of "Naari Sansargas"(associations with women) including even talking or looking at them.

Because,even glancing at a women can be considered as contrary to celibacy,as the [Daksha Smriti](http://www.yoga-age.com/modern/brahma.html) says:

> Thinking of a woman or her picture, praising a woman or her picture,
>   sporting with a woman or her picture, **glancing at a woman or her
>   picture,** secretly talking to a woman, thinking of a sinful action
>   towards a woman actuated by sensuality, determining upon the sinful
>   action, and bodily action resulting in the discharge of semen are the
>   eight characteristics of copulation; **and Brahmacharya is quite
>   contrary to all these eight indications**.

So, a sanyasi or even only a brahmachari(like students) carefully avoid women as much as possible.

The Manu Smriti even says:

> 2.215. One should not sit in a lonely place with one’s mother, sister, or daughter; for the senses are powerful, and master even a learned
>   man.

Quoting from the "[Ashtanga Yoga-the Significant Means of Shiva Tatwa](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/lingapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=3)" chapter of the Linga Purana :

> To control the activities or goings on in the mind is Yoga. The 
>   Ashtanga or Eight-Limbed Yoga comprises of Yama- Niyama- Aasana-
>   Pranaayama- Pratyahara-Dharana-Dhyana-Samadhi. Yama is denoted by good
>   behaviour comprising Ahimsa (Non-Violence), Satya         (Truth),
>   Asteya (stealing), **Brahmacharya (avoidance of sex)** and Aparigraha
>   or  Excessive acquisition. Basic Niyamas is in fact an extension of
>   Yama:  To refrain from hurting or torturing co-Beings physically or
>   mentally is Ahimsa; to convey whatever is seen, heard, and believed is
>   Satya  unless it does not hurt any body is known as Satya; to desist
>   stealing of other’s property by deed, thought or otherwise is called
>   Asteya;  to**negate from relationship with another female or in
>   respect of a female  wih another  male, excepting the wedded woman or
>   man as the case may  be and this should be observed by *vision*,
>   thought or deed is called  Brahmacharya or celibacy;**

So, a Yogi or Sanyasi ,who follows the eight-fold path of Yoga ,avoids all forms of women associations as a part of his spiritual development and also to avoid chances of breaking his sanyasa or brahmacharya vows.

Comment: Thankyou for your quick response. It is very interesting however, who makes those rules?

Comment: The Dharma Shastras and other Hindu Scriptures contains the rules to be followed by a Sannyasi.

Comment: Who wrote the Dharma Shastra?

Comment: There are many Dharma Shastras called the "Smritis".They are compiled by Saints like Yajnavalkya,Vashistha,Parashara and also by Swambhyu Manu.There r mainly 18 of them.Many others are also there.Apart from that there 18 major Puranas all of them compiled by Maharshi Vyasa.All of those comprise vital part of Hindu Scriptures.

Comment: The only thing to add is that the same goes for women sadhus, they have guidelines not to look at men. The objective is to make the mind pure by renouncing lust and greed. See Gita  II. 59- 64 and V. 23-29.

Comment: @Rickross why not then Vivekananda followed it in the case of Nivedita?

Comment: @Rakesh Joshi Swami Vivekanada must have won over senses completely..obviously he was too confident about his self control..Sannyasis in general wud avoid luking at women simply because that can ignite lust in their mind which is the last thing they want..

Comment: @Rickross so this rules are only for those who have not won over the senses ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi .the sannyasis follow such practices for their own good..and yes all sannyasis follow such practices..Now why swami Vivekananda behaved in a certain way and not in the other way is not for me to tell..If he initiated Nivedita then what is wrong in it?Is that not allowed for sannyasis?

Comment: @Rickross show me where is it allowed  ? Sankara or ramanuja etc do not  initiate women.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi That is irrelevant to this question..So we can talk in chatroom..

Comment: the word 'picture' doesn't appear in the actual ślokas. https://archive.org/details/ashtadash-smriti-18-smritis-pt.-sundar-lal-tripathi/page/n473/mode/2up?view=theater It's added by Sivananda in his work 'Practice of Brahmacarya' Even then the Skt words include picture viewing, etc. too. 
It's important for brahmacārins, saṁnyāsins and those practicing yoga (Pātañjala), to uphold brahmacarya, as you said. A gṛhastha man commits no doṣa on indulging in any of the 8 types of maithuna with his patnī. But he should avoid this with women other than his wife (or wives).

Answer (score 6):

It is not just male Sannyasis not looking at women. Women Sannyasis must also avoid men. The reason for avoidance is given in the passage posted below.

> **Man dangerous to woman in the spiritual path**
>
> Just as a woman is a danger to a man desiring progress on the
>   spiritual path, so is a man to woman. It is the man who is uxorious,
>   and engrossed too much with women, that gets a woman’s body in the
>   next birth. Having become a woman, and being unaware that it is My
>   binding power of Maya, as dictated by her Karma, that approached her
>   as husband offering her wealth, children and home, **she succumbs to
>   these attractions to Maya without knowing that they mark her spiritual
>   doom, even as a male deer meets with its death at the hands of a
>   hunter who attracts it by his musical call imitating the mating cry of
>   the female.**

Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.31.41-42