# Why are women and men asked to sit separate in religious gatherings?

Tags: women, indriyas

I regularly attend a religious *sabha* in which men sit on the right and women on the left (sometimes its men in-front and women at the back). Why are we suggested to sit seperate?

Is it because we have to act as brahmacharis and carefully avoid women as much as possible as said by a fellow user Rickross in this post [Why do Sannyasis avoid looking at women?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15773/why-do-sannyasis-avoid-looking-at-women)

Comment: Women are always allotted separate places almost everywhere like in transports they have separate seats/compartments.Same kind of intent might be working here.Also,i think, it simplifies crowd management.

Comment: Also i presume that the ladies may feel uneasy sitting among guys.

Comment: I think one of the reason also is for ease  and confortness.Generally ladies will experience more confort and easyness when  surrounded by ladies , than surrounded by unknown  men. This arrangment also helps in keeping discipline and concentration level of audience  at that  place and prevents unnesscery interaction among crowd.