# In brahmachayra what do I do with pent up sexual energy?

Tags: sex, chakras, brahmacharya

When I have a lot of sexual excitement and sexual energy in my lower chakra, what do I need to do to stop this? Do I channel the energy to higher chakra?

Isn't the goal to not get sexually excited in order for the semen to get transmuted into Ojas?

Comment: first, control whatever enters your stomach. avoid meat, alcohol, onion & garlic. and reduce salt and spices intake. since food affects mind, your sensual feelings (rajo guna) will decrease. right now, it's like a child trying to control a horse. either the child needs to get much stronger, or the horse needs to get much smaller. while it will take time for your thoughts to mature, it will take much less time for you to control what you eat. just try fasting for one day, or go on a fruits-only diet. you will immediately see the difference in clarity of mind free from hankering desires.

Comment: firstly, good to know that you are trying to follow the ancient science of "shakti upasana". Welcome and good luck. @ram has said it correctly. But pl. let's know whether you had your "shakti-jagaran" (initiation) by an able "guru"? Because when the "Kundalini" gets moving, firstly it encounters the "mooladhara" chakra. It instigates, many a times, sexual response. How to control it, what precautions, etc. has to be entrusted to your "Guru". Otherwise it may be disastrous. It is not a child's play. I am not discouraging you, but trying to caution.

Comment: To start with, your best bet would be "Vipassana" IMHO. There are loads of courses available online (just google it), but go for one by Late Shri. Goenka. It doesn't require any particular religion, or any equipment or whatever. Just sit, relax, and observe the things such as breath -- as they happen. I am not an authority on it, so better you follow the videos by Goenka.

Comment: @Vineet I don't play with Kundalini yoga because I could harm myself. But surely, I could stop sexual thoughts and think of more abstract things. The problem is sexual urge, but for now I only know that meditation, diet, hatha yoga, thinking about scriptures and mantra will work I think.

Comment: Surely, meditation (dhyan), diet, scriptures would help you. Regarding Hatha Yoga and 'Beej Mantra', it should be taken from a Guru. But you can always chant "nama mantra".

Comment: @Vineet most of the people who talk of dangers of kundalini dont have first hand experience themselves and it is a hearsay. Spiritual path is for brave so its not good to discourage someone. Secondly this is Hinduism forum so i think not good to promote Buddhist stuff.

Comment: @ram we can avoid alcohol and meat but his situation of body will be worse if he go fasting .I am i right?

Comment: this is very similar to another question and may be a duplicate. Do a search on ojas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "Brahm" in "Brahmacharya"? How does it relate to celibacy?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/what-is-brahm-in-brahmacharya-how-does-it-relate-to-celibacy) @SwamiVishwananda

Answer (score 10):

you can not just stop having sexual thoughts, you have to replace the sexual thoughts with something else.

1. First is to have satvik food and stop seeing sexual explicit movies, sexually explicit TV serials. Do not have intoxicants (very very important). Refrain from using sexually swear words.
2. Remember God as omni-present, esp. in morning and when going to sleep
3. Most importantly, whenever sexual thoughts occur then think that "you have taken million/billions of rebirths, many times even as human girl and many times as human boy and animals. When you were girl million times, then you were sexually thinking towards boy, and now when you are boy , then you are thinking towards girl sexually. Now, all this is just play of these bodies, so now the time has come to get rid of these bodily urges, which you have played million times, now the time is for your consciousness urges to take over your bodily urges." You may also imagine to be present in your previous life as girl(or boy) yourself, that may also stop sexual thoughts towards girls(or boys). For some people, visiting cemetry or cremation ground every week and viewing atleast 5 dead bodies being done with last rites and 'imagining themselves there after few decades' - helps soak there pent up sexual energy, by practically reminding them  their "this bodily fate"(not their consciousness fate). Think of Swami Vivekananda(or somebody alike him as it suits you) seeing you and esp. your mind - openly from above and nearby.
4. You may do kundalini yoga. Or, if you do not want to do kundalini yoga, then you may do yogic exercise of upside down pose. http://www.rivagyoga.com/blog/2015/6/18/10-reasons-to-get-upside-down-everyday
5. If you still are not able to control it, then take a cold shower.

But you should not depend upon step 5 etc, actually step3 is what, we should depend upon in mid-way. And Ultimately best is to depend upon meditation. When you will have total command over your mind and thoughts, then you will not need any of steps, even when you see a nude opposite-sex person in front of you, your mind will neither be attracted towards it, nor averse to it, it will be having a unaffected neutral attitude towards it. When you achieve total control of your mind, soul - then your mind will not wander until you deliberately turn your will power towards sexual act as a loving duty/dharma of grihastha(householder layman) - for creating progeny within marraige ; but it will not wander just for wasting the precious sperm.

---

see also: 
  - [How do I control and slay indriyas (senses)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-do-i-control-and-slay-indriyas-senses)

Comment: Just curious! Where did you find this whole content ? Also why did you say "the precious sperm" ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto , He said 'the precious sperm' because if preserved, it has the potential to get transformed into 'ojas'. When men ejaculate, it gets downward motion (adhogami). If it gets the upwards path by practicing 'raja yoga', it gets upliftment. (source :- Raja Yoga by Swami Vivekanand).

Comment: @Vineet Thank you for reply! I am not sure how to ask, but what is this Ojas used for ? because as you mentioned if sperm preserved, it gets transformed into Ojas. So at the end it's sperm only. Also would be great if you can drop in [Agama chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53977/agama-and-tantra) for more discussion on it.

Comment: Ojas helps in "shakti jagaran" (kundalini awakening). Sperm is tangible matter whereas ojas is intangible (containing divine powers within). A similar (not perfect) analogy would be -- charcoal is an earthly matter, black, amourphous. But when used in boilers, it emits heat (already contained within it), it would be used to make steam, to run turbines, to produce electricity.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto: I will sadly not be able to give you a reference for this. [ The point number 3 is entirely  100% my own conceptualization.] [But Rest of the points are crux of my own deliberations based on my three decades of reading (reading of hindu scriptures and tidbits on suggestions on journey of sex life by hindu sages here and there), intermixed with my own observations. Even then in this case, all the words were typed from scratch by myself without any reference.So I will not be able to point a single/few reference for even the rest of the points.] But if it works,then its fine :-)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto: for the 'precious sperm' , 'Vineet' is right, sperm can be converted into ojas and spiritual energy, thats why it is precious.  If you suppress sperm natural tendencies, then it creates problem; hence you need to convert it into ojas and spiritual energy to provide the outlet to it. (this particular point on sperm, I am talking from Vivekananda, Osho and Sri Aurbindo ; but I will not be able to pinpoint the exact reference text now)

Comment: @zaxebo1 So in that case it'll only be converted to ojus if one person is doing spiritual practices ? What one is not doing and is not wasting by ejaculation ?

Comment: Even if a person is not doing meditation etc., but observing "brahmacharya" by body and mind, and conserving the sperm, he is ought to get benefits. (ref. :- Swami Vivekananda's "Raj Yog" and rememberances written by his disciples in one out of total 10 volumes published by "Ramakrishna Mission"). To be precise, once Swamiji was reading Encyclopedia. After completing reading, while discussing brahmacharya, he asked a person to open any page and tell the page no. After this, he told about the subject on that page and details about it. He said this was due to Brahmacharya by body and mind.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do some type of Yoga to control lust. The easiest method is to repeat the name of God.

> A DEVOTEE: "Sir, should one first practise discrimination to attain
>   self-control?"
>
> MASTER: "That is also a path. It is called the path of vichara,
>   reasoning. But the inner organs (Mind (manas), intelligence (buddhi),
>   mind-stuff (chitta), and ego (ahamkara).) are brought under control
>   naturally through the path of devotion as well. It is rather easily
>   accomplished that way. Sense pleasures appear more and more tasteless
>   as love for God grows. Can carnal pleasure attract a grief-stricken
>   man and woman the day their child has died?"
>
> DEVOTEE: "How can I develop love for God?"
>
> MASTER: "Repeat His name, and sins will disappear. Thus you will
>   destroy lust, anger, the desire for creature comforts, and so on."
>
> DEVOTEE: "How can I take delight in God's name?"
>
> MASTER: "Pray to God with a yearning heart that you may take delight
>   in His name. He will certainly fulfil your heart's desire."

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 9, Advice to the Brahmos, Sunday, April 8, 1883